# How To Check If A Model Has A Reference To It

Tags: django

Say I have an address (think street address) model in django and that is referenced by jobs (think job sites) and customers (think mailing addresses).

When executing a query, is it possible to filter only rows which do not have a reference to them?

**Models**

```
class Address(models.Model):

    street = models.TextField()
    suite = models.TextField()
    city = models.TextField()
    state = models.TextField()
    county = models.TextField(default="")
    country = models.TextField(default= "USA")
    zip = models.TextField()
    notes = models.TextField()

class Customer(models.Model ):

    firstname = models.TextField(null=False)
    lastname = models.TextField(blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,null=True,blank=True,default=None)

class Job(models.Model):

    number=models.IntegerField(null=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,null=True)
```

**Desired Functionality**

```
#get all addresses that don't have a job or customer referencing it
addresses = Address.objects.filter(job_set_count = 0, customer_set_count=0)
```

**PS**

Would this be the scenario to use the "OneToOne" relationship?

Comment: `addresses = Address.objects.filter(job__isnull=True, customer__isnull=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

from django.db.models import Q

addresses = Address.objects.filter(Q(job__isnull=True) & Q(customer__isnull=True))

Answer (score 0):

Change the relationship of Address to customer. 
It is not possible multiple customers have one address (according to your Address model class). So the relationship of your models can be one of them

1. One customer have multiple addresses.
2. One customer have one address.